# Weird vertical gaps when including the setspace package in a scrbook class document

Tags: spacing, scrbook, setspace, vertical-spacing

In my own class I load the class `scrbook` in the following way:

```
\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, BCOR1.5cm, appendixprefix, 
    cleardoublepage  = empty, numbers = noenddot, bibliography = totoc]{scrbook}
```

Moreover, I'm including the `setspace` package via `\usepackage{setspace}`. In need this package for the first chapter only. However, including this package produces weird vertical gaps between paragraphs, theorems and their proofs; similar to what's described in this question: [Problem with large gaps in scrreprt with setspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/207718/181897).

Unfortunately, I can't share my document and I'm not able to reproduce the problem easily. But if I remove the `usepackage{setspace}` (or change the document class to `book`) the vertical gaps dissapper. Can I somehow undo the changes made by including the `setspace` package after the first chapter?

**EDIT**: Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{test}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{setspace}

\begin{document}

\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
    \begin{doublespace}
        {\fontsize{18}{0}\selectfont\textbf{A Bcdefg hijklmnop qrstuvwx yz abc defghij klmnopq 
rs tuv wxyzab cdef Ghijklmnop Qrstuvwx yzabcdefg}}\\[30pt]
    \end{doublespace}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

test.cls:

```
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}
\ProvidesClass{test}

\LoadClass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, BCOR=1.5cm, appendixprefix, cleardoublepage=empty, numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}
```

Comment: Please clarify the following matters: With which options (if any) do you load the `setspace` package? How, exactly, do you invoke non-singlespacing at the start of chapter 1? It is the impression that the "weird vertical gap" issues do not surface if non-singlespacing is in effect? And, how exactly do you switch (back) to singlespacing at the end of chapter 1 (or at the start of chapter 2)?

Comment: Off topic: you will get a warning regarding the obsolete option `DIV1.5cm` in your code snippet. You should replace it by `DIV=1.5cm` to avoid the automatical usage of `version=first` and `enabledeprecatedfontcommands`.

Comment: @esdd What exactly do you mean? You mean I should replace the `BCOR1.5cm`?

Comment: @Mico I don't load `setspace` with an option. Actually, I'm only using the `setspace` package to print a single paragraph using the `doublespace` environment. Can I achieve the same effect in a different way so that I can remove the `setspace` package?

Comment: @0xbadf00d You should replace `BCOR1.5cm` by `BCOR=1.5cm`.

Comment: @esdd Thanks for the remark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention in a comment that you're "only using the `setspace` package to print a single paragraph using the `doublespace` environment." In cases such as this one, loading the `setspace` package must surely be too much of a good thing.

I suggest that you not load the `setspace` package. Instead, you could issue the instruction

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.667}\normalfont % or whatever multiplicative factor you fancy
```

immediately *before* the start of the paragraph in question and insert the instruction

```
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.0}\normalfont
```

immediately *after* the end of the paragraph.

A full MWE (minimum working example):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, twoside, openright, 
   BCOR=1.5cm, appendixprefix, cleardoublepage=empty,
   numbers=noenddot, bibliography=totoc]{scrbook}

\usepackage{lipsum} % filler text
\begin{document}
\lipsum[2] % a paragraph of filler text

\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.667}\normalfont
\lipsum[2] % ditto, but double-spaced

\bigskip
\renewcommand\baselinestretch{1}\normalfont
\lipsum[2] % ditto, back to single-spacing
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I've tried what you suggested, but it has no effect. I've added a minimal example to the question.

Comment: @0xbadf00d - Please clarify what you mean by `it has no effect`.

Comment: I've removed the `doublespace` environment. But then the rendered output is the same with and without the code you've suggested.

Comment: @0xbadf00d - Thanks for editing your question and telling us more about the document class, and class options, you employ. Please see my updated answer -- it should work with your setup now.

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that `1.667` is precisely the factor used by the `doublespace` environment?

Comment: @0xbadf00d - Indeed, that's the case. (Just look inside the file `setspace.sty`.) Why 1.667? Because most fonts have a baselineskip that's 20% larger than the nominal font size, and 1.2*1.667=2.0. Do be aware, though, that the term 'double-spacing' is not uniquely defined across word processors and typesetting systems.