# Blank spaces when using setspace and twoside

Tags: double-sided, setspace, scrreprt

I have a question regarding the latex file of my thesis. My preamble looks like this

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, openright, DIV=calc]{scrreprt}
```

If I add `\usepackage{setspace}` to my code, some ugly blank spaces appear between the proof, text  or theorem environments. How can I solve this problem?

I think using the option onehalfspacing makes the pdf look nicer, appart from the nasty spaces.

Here is the link to the same question with some code examples. 
[Problem with large gaps in scrreprt with setspace](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/207718/problem-with-large-gaps-in-scrreprt-with-setspace/268081)
Unfortunately, the answers couldn't help solve my problem. Maybe there are some more ideas.

Thank you very much in advance!!

Comment: Welcome! Could you please add a minimal complete code example which shows your problem?

Comment: As always on this site you are much much more likely to get any help if you provide a full (but minimal) example of the problem you face. As you post no relevant code, we can only guess.

Comment: I added a link in my post. Maybe now it's clearer?

Comment: No, add code that show us your problem, Without code from you, what exactly can we do? Note that preparing such code is a valuable debugging tool and you will often find the problem for yourself.

Comment: Actually, using `\onehalfspacing` makes the PDF look worse, but this is personal opinion. If the answers don't fit to your case, it probably means your case is different, that's why some code of yours is needed.

Comment: Also note that is is a good idea to @name the person you are responding to in a comment, then they get notified. Else you have to hope they come back to your question at some point

Answer (score 1):

I just found out that \raggedbottom works! I just did the mistake to put it in the line

```
\documentclass[12pt, a4paper, twoside, raggedbottom, openright, DIV=calc]{scrreprt}
```

Instead it works perfectly if you just put it before begin document

```
\raggedbottom
\begin{document}
```